# iOS Framework Version Won't Change

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I have a Swift-based iOS framework called BoKit.  I am trying to use the `BoKitVersionNumber` from BoKit.h to determine which version of the framework I am testing.  Trouble is, I can't get this number to update.

I have changed the versionto 0.10 in my project settings under Build Settings -> Linking -> Current Library Version.

[image]

I have then repeatedly done a clean and rebuild.  But the `BoKitVersionNumber` is still 1.0, which was the default before I made the change.

Doing a grep, I can see in my project folder, that this is defined in DerivedSources/BoKit_vers.c:

`$ egrep -r BoKitVersionNumber *
BoKit/BottleKit/BoKit.h:FOUNDATION_EXPORT double BoKitVersionNumber;
BoKit/build/BoKit.build/Release-iphoneos/BoKit.build/DerivedSources/BoKit_vers.c: const unsigned char BoKitVersionString[] __attribute__ ((used)) = "@(#)PROGRAM:BoKit  PROJECT:BoKit-1" "\n"; const double BoKitVersionNumber __attribute__ ((used)) = (double)1.;`

But I can't seem to get that file to change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to change is the *project version* (`CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION`) in the *Linking* section of your target's build settings.

[image]

Be aware that Apple only allows Major and Minor version numbers for the `BoKitVersionNumber`. Even if you specify a project version of `1.2.3` the `BoKitVersionNumber` will show just `1.2`. The `BoKitVersionString` on the other hand will reflect the correct version number, in your case `const unsigned char BoKitVersionString[] __attribute__ ((used)) = "@(#)PROGRAM:BoKit  PROJECT:BoKit-1.2.3"`.

You might also want to have a look at the Versioning section of the [Frameworks Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/VersionInformation.html).

Hope that helps!